# Declaration of PublicacionDao::add(Publicacion $obj) must be compatible with ICrud::add(object $obj)

Tags: php, poo, interface

Aca esta el codigo de mi interfaz

```php
<?php
    Interface ICrud{
        public function listAll();
        public function listById($id);
        public function add(Object $obj);
        public function update(Object $obj);
        public function delete($id);
    }
?>
```

Aca esta la clase que implementa mi interfaz y de paso el metodo add() que es el que me da error

```php
class PublicacionDao implements ICrud{
public function listAll(){}
        public function listById($id){}
        public function add(Publicacion $obj){
            $con= new Conexion();
            if( isset($obj) ){
                try{
                    $pdo = $con->conectarBD();
                    $query = "INSERT INTO `publicacion` 
                    (`id_publicacion`, `id_usuario_publica`,                            `titulo_publicacion`, 
                    `descripcion_publicacion`, `texto_publicacion`, `img_opcional_1`, 
                    `img_opcional_2`, `img_opcional_3`) 
                    VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
                    $stmt->execute( $obj->getIdPublicacion(), $obj->getIdUsuarioPublica(), 
                                    $obj->getTituloPublicacion(), $obj->getDescripcionPublicacion(), 
                                    $obj->getTextoPublicacion(), $obj->getImgOpcional1(), $obj->getImgOpcional2(), 
                                    $obj->getImgOpcional3() );
                }catch(Exception $e){
                    echo( 'Error: '.$e->getMessage() );
                }finally{
                    $con->desconetarDB();
                }
            }else{
                echo('No Data To Insert!');
            }
        }
        public function update(Object $obj){}
        public function delete($id){}
}
```

Error:
Fatal error:
Declaration of PublicacionDao::add(Publicacion $obj) must be compatible with ICrud::add(object $obj) in
C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\modelo\PublicacionDao.php
on line
6.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes. Por favor traduce la pregunta y coloca el código como texto, es difícil interpretarlo en imagen o copiarlo para probar.

Comment: pega el codigo y borra las imagenes, es mas facil para corregir la seccion que deba corregirse.